# MaxReceivedMessageSize too low

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, basichttpbinding

I'm getting a ServiceModel.CommunicationException saying that the MaxMessageSize property is not set for my bindings.  The issue is that both my client and WCF service have this property set in their app.config and web.config files respectively.  I'm assuming that the service reference in the client is not using the setting in the config, but I'm not sure why this isn't the case.

The error message:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.BufferMessageStream(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at InternetWalker.ProductManagerService.IProductManager.GetProducts()
       at InternetWalker.ProductManagerService.ProductManagerClient.GetProducts() in C:\Users\TechStation01\Source\Repos\ProductManager\InternetWalker\InternetWalker\Service References\ProductManagerService\Reference.cs:line 119
       at InternetWalker.ApiWrapper.GetProducts() in C:\Users\TechStation01\Source\Repos\ProductManager\InternetWalker\InternetWalker\Classes\ApiWrapper.cs:line 69
       at InternetWalker.MainWindowViewModel.GetProductsFromApi() in C:\Users\TechStation01\Source\Repos\ProductManager\InternetWalker\InternetWalker\MainWindowViewModel.cs:line 57
       at InternetWalker.MainWindow.GetProducts_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\TechStation01\Source\Repos\ProductManager\InternetWalker\InternetWalker\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 49
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at InternetWalker.App.Main() in C:\Users\TechStation01\Source\Repos\ProductManager\InternetWalker\InternetWalker\obj\Debug\Boilerplate\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
       InnerException:
```

The client app.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="DefaultEndpoint"
          address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding"
          contract="ProductManagerService.IProductManager"
          behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
      </endpoint>
    </client>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The webservice web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" batch="false" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ProductManagerService.ProductManager">
        <endpoint name="DefaultEndpoint" address="" contract="ProductManagerService.IProductManager" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Example of how the service is being called:

```
public static DataSet GetProducts()
{
    ProductManagerService.ProductManagerClient proxy = new ProductManagerService.ProductManagerClient();
    DataSet productSet = proxy.GetProducts();
    productSet = MapTables(productSet);
    return productSet;
}
```

As you can see, I have the MaxReceivedMessageSize set for the "DefaultBinding", but the error message is still referencing a max message size of 65536.

Comment: Every time you re-add or re-configure your service reference, you are going to have to repeat this step.  Your client applications will not inherit your service config behavior.

Comment: I suspect your service is **NOT** using your config. If you comment out the service in the config, does it still work?

Comment: Note that the issue is a client-side issue, it has nothing to do with your service.  Can you post an example of how you are calling the service from your application?

Comment: Added the example of the call. rene, I think thats probably true.  This worked previously without the service being added in the app.config, so I was suprised when I was running into answers that involved adding that.